# Why are FunctionN types in Scala created as a subtype of AnyRef, not AnyVal?

Tags: scala

If I understand correctly, under the JVM, every time I use a lambda expression, an Object has to be created.

Why the overhead? Why did the Scala creators choose to extend AnyRef instead of AnyVal when designing FunctionN types? I mean, they don't have any real 'values' in them by themselves, so shouldn't it be possible for functions to be value objects with an underlying Unit representation (or a long containing some hash for equality checking or whatever)? I can imagine not allocating an object per every lambda can lead to performance boosts in some codebases.

One obvious disadvantage that comes to my mind of extending AnyVal is that it would prohibit subclassing function types. Maybe that alone would be sufficient to be not extending AnyVal, but what other reasons can there be?

--Edit

I understand that functions need to close over other variables, but I think it would be more natural to model it as arguments to the apply method, not field members of FunctionN objects (thus removing the necessity to have a java.lang.Object on this part) -- after all, isn't what variables are closed over all known at compile time?

--Edit again

I found out about it; what I had in mind was 'lambda lifting'.

Comment: Functions do have "real values" in them: ones they close over.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only ways to call a method are the bytecode operations `invokevirtual` (virtual dispatch on class), `invokeinterface` (same, but on interfaces), `invokespecial` (invoke *exactly* the given method, ignoring virtual lookup. Used for `private`, `super`, and `new`.), and `invokestatic` (<s>summon unicorns</s> call `static` method). `invokespecial` is out, because calling exactly some function is the antithesis of abstracting over a function. `invokestatic` is out, too, because it's essentially an `invokespecial` clone that doesn't need a `this` argument. `invokevirtual` and `invokeinterface` are similar enough for our purposes to be considered the same.

There's no way to pass a plain function pointer like you might see in C, and even if you could, you could never call it, as there is no instruction that can jump to an arbitrary point in code. (All jump targets inside a method are restricted to that method, and all references to the outside boil down to strings. (The JVM, of course, is free to optimize that representation once a file is loaded.))

In order to invoke a method with either instruction, the JVM must look up the method inside the target object's virtual dispatch table. If you tried to dummy out the object with `()` (`AnyVal` subclasses didn't exist until 2.10, but let's suspend our disbelief), then the JVM would get horribly confused when you tried to call a (presumably interesting) method on something that's as close to "featureless blob" as you can get.

Also remember that an object's methods are totally determined by its class. If `a.getClass == b.getClass`, then `a` and `b` have the *exact same* methods, code and all. In order to get around this, we need to create subclasses of the `FunctionN` traits, such that each subclass represents one function, and each instance of each class contains a reference to its class which contains a reference to the code associated with that function. Even with `invokedynamic`, this is still true, as the `LambdaMetaFactory`'s current implementation creates an inner class at runtime.

Finally, the assumption that functions need no state is false, as @Oleg points out. Closures need to keep references to their environment, and that is only possible with an object.